# Why did this reselect selector cause a re-render?

Tags: reactjs, redux, reselect

One of my components was re-rendering, and I realised it was because of the allPageViews selector below:

```
const getPages = (state: IAppState) => {
  return state.pages;
};


export const attachPageViews = createSelector(
  getPages,
  (pages) => pages.pageViews
);
export const selectPageViews = createSelector(
  attachPageViews,
  (pageViews) => pageViews
);


export const allPageViews = createSelector(
  selectPageViews,
  (pageStore: PageViewStore) => {
    let returnedPageViews: PageView[] = [];
    for (const section of Object.values(pageStore.sections)) {
      for (const page of Object.values(section!.pageViews)) {
        returnedPageViews = [...returnedPageViews, page!];
      }
    }
    return returnedPageViews;
  }
);
```

When I was dispatching an action I was changing the pages reducer, but not the pageViews contained inside (pages have another key called data that I was updating). So by my understanding selectPageViews should not change (because the underlying pageViews are not changing) and so allPageViews should just be memoizing and not re-calculating because nothing has been updated.

Nonetheless, it was re-calculating. When I moved the returnedPageViews array and the for loops into the component that was using useSelector() then the component stopped re-rendering.

So my question is - how is Reselect working, and why did it re-calculate and trigger the re-render when the array was being made in allPageViews?

Answer (score 0):

> I was changing the pages reducer, but not the pageViews contained inside (pages has another key called data that I was updating). So by my understanding selectPageViews should not change (because the underlying pageViews are not changing) and so allPageViews should just be memoising and not re-calculating because nothing has been updated.

That is correct, state.page.pageViews did not change so `selectPageViews` will return memoized result and so will allPageViews.

> Nonetheless it was re-calculating. When I moved the returnedPageViews array and the for loops into the component that was using useSelector() then the component **stopped re-rendering**. So my question is - how is Reselect working, and why did it re-calculate and **trigger the re-render** when the array was being made in allPageViews?

That makes no sense, so the selector is not is triggering re rendering? And `Nonetheless it was re-calculating` is not true, here is your code below demonstrating that your initial assumption was correct; if you don't change state.page.pageViews then both selectPageViews and allPageViews will return their memoized result (will not re calculate):

```js
const { createSelector } = Reselect;
const getPages = (state) => {
  return state.pages;
};

const attachPageViews = createSelector(
  getPages,
  (pages) => pages.pageViews
);
//this one is kind of useless, it does x=>x so you may as
//  well do: const selectPageViews = attachPageViews
const selectPageViews = createSelector(
  attachPageViews,
  (pageViews) => {
    console.log(
      'selectPageViews logs once but is called twice'
    );
    return pageViews;
  }
);

const allPageViews = createSelector(
  selectPageViews,
  (pageStore) => {
    console.log(
      'allPageViews logs once but is called twice'
    );
    return { new: 'object', pageStore };
  }
);
const state = {
  pages: {
    pageViews: { value: 'this is page views' },
  },
};
console.log('calling allPageViews first time');
const one = allPageViews(state);
console.log('calling allPageViews second time with changed state.pages');
const two = allPageViews({
  ...state,
  pages: {
    ...state.pages,
    changedSomething: true,
  },
});
console.log('both results are the same:',one === two);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/reselect/4.0.0/reselect.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As from my experience, it will re-render when any dependency in side createSelector recompute, such as

```
 const dep2 = createSelector(
    dep4,
    dep5,
    (a, b) => a * b;
```

```
   dep1,
   dep2,
   dep3,
   (a, b, c) => d
```

the last one will recompute whenever d2 is compute